# An example of a linear map such that $Ker(f) \cap Im(f) \neq {0}$ and $f: R^2 \to R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

An example of a linear map such that $Ker(f) \cap Im(f) \neq {0}$.

I have a feeling that such a linear map does not exist, but I could neither come with an example nor prove that there's no linear map with such property.

I feel that if the intersection is not null then the Kernal must be a subspace of the Image, this immediately implies that $dim Ker(f) = 1$. Because if it were equal to zero then the intersection would be zero, if it were equal to two then the dimension of the image would be zero.

So it must be that $Ker f = Im f$ for the intersection not to be null and both are of dimension one. I cannot find an example where this property is verified.

P.S: $f: R^2 \to R^2$

Comment: Hint: you're only looking for a nonzero $y$ such that $f(y) = 0$ and such that $\exists x,\, y = f(x)$. So effectively you're looking for $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x) = y \neq 0$ and $f(y) = 0$.

Comment: Just pick two nonzero, noncolinear vectors $x$ and $y$, define $f(x) = y$ and $f(y) = 0$... And since you're in $R^2$ you might as well pick $x = (1, 0)$ and $y = (0, 1)$... Can $f$ be extended to a linear map on $R^2$? Why or why not?

Comment: Hint: pick some basis $u,v$ where $fv = 0$. What must $fu$ be?

Comment: @Stef So basically a matrix whose square is null. Basically the linear map associated to the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $ will do the job, and so will any matrix whose square is nul, right?

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh Yes exactly!